# How to do migration in Sequelize on existing models using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

First I build the models using sequelize define like this:
**user.model.js**

```
  module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const User = sequelize.define("users", {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },

    username: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      notEmpty: true,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        min: 8,
        max: 24,
      },
    },

    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true,
      },
    },

    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    confirmationCode: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    active: {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM,
      values: ['Pending', 'Active'],
      defaultValue: 'Pending'
    },
    passwordResetToken: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    passwordResetExpire: { type: Sequelize.DATE },
    passwordChangedAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE },
  });

  return User;
};
```

Now i want to do migration.When i do **npx sequelize-cli init** it create default folders and change my model index file: **Before**

```
    const config = require("../config/db.config.js");
    const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.DB, config.USER, config.PASSWORD, {
  host: config.HOST,
  dialect: config.dialect,
  operatorsAliases: 0,
  logging: false,
  pool: {
    max: config.pool.max,
    min: config.pool.min,
    acquire: config.pool.acquire,
    idle: config.pool.idle,
  },
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.user = require("../model/user.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.role = require("../model/role.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.images = require("./image.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.billingAddress = require("./billingAddress.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);

db.role.belongsToMany(db.user, {
  through: "user_roles",
  foreignKey: "roleId",
  otherKey: "userId",
});
db.user.belongsToMany(db.role, {
  through: "user_roles",
  foreignKey: "userId",
  otherKey: "roleId",
});

db.user.hasOne(db.billingAddress, { foreignKey: "userId" });

db.ROLES = ["user", "admin", "moderator"];
module.exports = db;
```

**After**

```
    'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

**So how can I perform migration? I already checked lots of code but did not get any proper solution**

I already checked Sequelize official documentation but didn't get anything.

I already define schema without sequelize-cli but for migration, we need to create sequelize models How do I perform migration in this situation? if anyone has done similar problem please send me the solution.
............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: I know only one way: describe all tables in migration in a similar way you already did for models.